# twoside page, outside border on right side smaller than on the left

Tags: margins, double-sided

I have to hand in my thesis tomorrow and it's not working. I want to print it like a book (print front and rear of a page). That's why I am using twopages. But the outside border is different for the right and the left page.
My code

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
 \usepackage{fontenc}
 \usepackage[hcentering,bindingoffset=9mm]{geometry}
 \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}
 \setlength{\textwidth}{15,5cm}
 \setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
```

What do I have to change that the outside border of the riht and left page are the same size (and the inside border too)?
Thank you soooooooooooooooooo much!!!!!

Comment: Don't set the values for `\textwidth`  and similar ones by yourself, do all this using package `geometry`. BTW: Giving a minimal, compilable working example raises chances of a good aanswer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure to understand.

If you want odd and even pages to have the same margins, you can call `geometry` with the option `asymmetric`.

For example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want right and left margins to have the same width, that is to have the same look of a one-sided document, you have to add the option `hcentering` (but in this case I wouldn't understand why using `twoside`).

For example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[asymmetric,hcentering]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]